# color datapoints according to specific value in a column

Tags: r, plot, colors

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c('hio.k2','fhuei.k1','buew.k2'),col2=c(1,4,5.5))
> df
      col1 col2
1   hio.k2  1.0
2 fhuei.k1  4.0
3  buew.k2  5.5
```

I want to plot df and assign colors to the data. The groups for the coloring are defined `.k1` or`.k2`in `col1`.
I tried

```
color = rep(NA, length=length(df$col2))
color[which(df$col2=="*k1")] = "red"
color[which(df$col2=="*k2"))] = "blue"
```

That is not working. I think the issue is  `*`. What can I do to assign a color according to `k1`  or  `k2` in `col1` ?

I want color to look like this

```
color
'blue','red','blue'
```

for the plot

```
hist <- ggplot(df) + 
  geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = `col2`),show.legend = TRUE,color = color) +
```

Comment: What plot are you trying to make?

Comment: I added information to the plot.@Edo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the barchart you required. (I guess you meant a barchart and not a histogram)

```
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(df) +
    geom_col(aes(x = col1, y = col2, fill = stringr::str_sub(col1, -2, -1))) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(k2 = "blue", k1 = "red")) +
    labs(fill = "K")
```

[image]

Though, I believe that default colours are better:

```
ggplot(df) +
    geom_col(aes(x = col1, y = col2, fill = stringr::str_sub(col1, -2, -1))) +
    labs(fill = "K") +
    theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Could also be with the regex `fill = sub('.*\\.(.*$)', '\\1', col1)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this approach using `ggplot2` from `tidyverse` and some data manipulation to get the color variable:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- data.frame(col1=c('hio.k2','fhuei.k1','buew.k2'),col2=c(1,4,5.5))
#Separate and create bar
df %>% mutate(dup=col1) %>% separate(col = dup,into = c('dup','coln'),sep = '\\.') %>%
  select(-dup) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x=col1,y=col2,color=coln))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('k1'='red','k2'='blue'))+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]